# Dynamic chart with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm writing an Excel macro that creates charts with dynamic ranges (i.e. that update automatically whenever a new row of data is added - https://trumpexcel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Dynamic-Chart-Range-in-Excel-Demo.gif). For the example I'm testing, my data is in columns A and B.

I do know this can be done through either tables or defined ranges, but unfortunately neither of those work for this particular project.

The code I'm currently using (two different versions) create the graph fine without me explicitly defining the range. However, when I add a new row of data, the graphs do not update.

```
Sub AddGraphs()
    'Set the dynamic ranges
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Create the chart
    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, LC))
        .Location xlLocationAsObject, "Sheet1"
    End With

    'Format chart and set location
    With ActiveChart
        .Parent.Top = Cells(1, LC + 3).Top
        .Parent.Left = Cells(1, LC + 3).Left
        .HasLegend = False
    End With
End Sub

'Alternative code

Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim ShName As String
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng1 = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow & ", B2:B" & LastRow)
        ShName = .Name
    End With
    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1

        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShName
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to have a macro to update (remove and replace) the data series in the named shape to utilize the new last rows.  I have had my best luck looping through and removing data series then adding in exactly what I want.  Edit:  You could set this up that the macro runs as a change event, when you add data to column 1 or 2, and the last row of each are equal (so you don't have it running all the time.

Comment: @cyril Thank you! Three questions if that's okay. a. Is the "the last row of each one are equal" to make sure the macro isn't triggered whenever just one of the columns updates? b. Would I be able to add lines to the code above to make it run as a change event, or do I need to write a different loop? c. Whenever I re-run the macro, it generates a new chart instead of updating the existing one. Any ideas on how to address this?

Comment: In your original code, you need to `.Name` your shape so you can later use that name.  Throw a `.Name = "Usable_Name"` in your `with activechart` section.  you should then be able to have your change even act upon `Sheets("Name").ChartObjects("Usable_Name")` by removing and adding specific data series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Shapes` to create the chart only on your activesheet, not create a chart-sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddGraphs()
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, ch As ChartObject
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Name = "Cat" '<--- Used Shapes to keep this on the sheet only
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Cat").Select '<--- Naming the Chart to later call and use in Change_Event
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, lc))
        .Location xlLocationAsObject, "Sheet1"
        .Parent.Top = Cells(1, lc + 3).Top
        .Parent.Left = Cells(1, lc + 3).Left
        .HasLegend = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Now, you have a chart made that you can use in the future.  You want your change event to be relevant to updating the data series only, like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Then Exit Sub
    ChartObjects("Cat").Select '<--- Using named shape/chart
    With ActiveChart
        Dim lr As Long, lc As Long
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, lc))
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Edit2:**  Redid post to fix a couple other things to make this work.

Comment: thank you for this! I think I understand what I'm doing a little better now. The only problem is that .Name = "Usable_name" seems to naming the sheet that the chart shows up on, not the chart itself (so under VBAProject > Microsoft Excel Objects it shows up as Chart1 (Name0)), and subsequently the change event can't locate it.

Comment: @wglass21 updated my post to be a bit better.  I forgot to put the chart name to the shape.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you. I think the assumption doesn't work either, since I'm getting a "sub or function not defined error" pointing to "Shapes".

Comment: @wglass21 See my updated answer... this is a bigger change.

Comment: @wglass21 Please mark this as answered if you are satisfied.  The checkmark to the left of the post will complete this question and list appropriately in the question queue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Cyril for the idea!

The code now updates as follows:

```
Option Explicit 'Excel worksheet change event Range A1 to B50
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:B50")) Is Nothing Then
            'Set the dynamic ranges

        Dim lr As Integer
        Dim lc As Integer

        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Create the chart
        Charts.Add
        With ActiveChart
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, lc))
            .Location xlLocationAsObject, "Sheet1"
        End With

    'Format chart and set location
        With ActiveChart
            .Parent.Top = Cells(1, lc + 3).Top
            .Parent.Left = Cells(1, lc + 3).Left
            .HasLegend = False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

This works great, except it creates a new chart every time the macro runs, and I would like to be updating the existing chart - would appreciate any help!